# asp.net access control's name in another control without using code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this is very simple & so silly for me to ask. 
Forgot what needs to be done.

How do i set the `name` property of txtNewPwd control as an attribute to txtConfPwd control's data-bv-identical-field attribute.

I do not want to use code-behind. tried #,=

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewPwd" runat="server" CssClass="form-control " placeholder="New Password"  TextMode="Password" required ClientIDMode="Static"
                    data-bv-stringLength="true" data-bv-stringLength-min="5" data-bv-stringLength-max="72" data-bv-stringLength-message="Enter 5-72 characters" MaxLength="72"                    
                    data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="Enter New Password"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtConfPwd" runat="server" CssClass="form-control " placeholder="Confirm Password"  TextMode="Password" required
                    data-bv-stringLength="true" data-bv-stringLength-min="5" data-bv-stringLength-max="72" data-bv-stringLength-message="Enter 5-72 characters" MaxLength="72"                    
                    data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="Enter New Password"
                     data-bv-identical="true"
                data-bv-identical-field="<%# txtNewPwd.UniqueID %>"
                data-bv-identical-message="The password and its confirm are not the same." 
                    ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery if you do not want to use code behind.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = $("#<%= txtNewPwd.ClientID %>").attr("name");
    $("#<%= txtConfPwd.ClientID %>").attr("data-bv-identical-field", name);
</script>
```

You could also use

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtConfPwd" runat="server" data-bv-identical-field='<%# txtNewPwd.UniqueID %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

This however requires `DataBind();` to be called in code behind, and you don't want that.

Comment: Since `ClientIdMode=Static`, no need for `$("#<%= txtNewPwd.ClientID %>")` just `$("#txtNewPwd")`..

Comment: @ibubi, true. But it is good practice when working with webforms.